# How to use $PYTHONPATH to change cwd

Tags: bash, unix, command

Goal: I want my run file `test_data_module.py` code via. bash in this working directory:

```sh
/home/me/.ssh/workers-python/workers/ontology_tagger/ontology_tagger/tests
```

Attempts:

```sh
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/danielbellio/.ssh/workers-python/workers/ontology_tagger/ontology_tagger/tests test_data_module.py
```

Error:

```sh
bash: test_data_module.py: command not found
```

Comment: If you write a command by just spelling its name - whether this is `cat` or `bash` or `python3` or, in your case, `test_data_module.py` -, the command must have the executable bit set and be located in one of the directories named in the variable `PATH`.  If this is not the case, you get a _command not found_ This is the basic mechanism of command execution in Unix-like systems, and neither related to Python nor to `PYTHONPATH`. I suggest that you remove the _python_ and _pythonpath_ tags from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an explicit path for your Python program, i.e.

```
 ~/your/script/dir/test_data_module.py
```

if the script is executable, or

```
python ~/your/script/dir/test_data_module.py
```

respectively

```
python3 ~/your/script/dir/test_data_module.py
```

if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

PYTHONPATH is a list of folders, not files, so try with `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/danielbellio/.ssh/workers-python/workers/ontology_tagger/ontology_tagger/`

Comment: That did nothing :( I also tried `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/danielbellio/.ssh/workers-python/workers/ontology_tagger/:/home/danielbellio/.ssh/workers-python/workers/ontology_tagger/ontology_tagger/` with no luck

Comment: @BenoitCourty : While this is correct, it is unrelated to the OPs problem. See my comment to the question.